# Colors of old circles on canvas recolor, why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

I'm trying to understand the combination of HTML5/CSS3 and Javascript more and more.
That's why I thought, make a little project so you learn all about that more.

In short, I like the new iOS7 wallpaper and use it on my website (http://www.betadevelops.com). Then I thought, let's make this more lightweight and draw it with pure Javascript.
I started and managed to get quite far (http://www.betadevelops.com/jOS7.html). But now I face a stupid problem I can't seem to get fixed.

I draw circles on the canvas, and dynamically assign colors to it. But each time a new circle (and so a new color gets chosen) it automatically recolors the old circles...
So let's say, 10 circles:
1: blue circle, draw's it and done
2: yellow circle, draw's it and done, but it also colors the first blue one to yellow

I also wanted to add opacity and blurring. The opacity kinda works in the sense it has opacity on only 2-3 circles from the 20 I draw. I think this is not possible because I use Math.Random the calculate a random opacity.
Considered the blurring, I can add blurring to the whole canvas with follow code

```
canvas.style.webkitFilter = "blur(3px)";
```

but that's not what I want. I want the blur on the circle itself and to be more precisely, the outline. I read about it and it's not possible, but you can mimmick the looks with using CSS box-shadow.
So I tried

```
canvas.style.webkitFilter = "box-shadow(10px 10px 5px #888)";
```

but this also doesn't work it seems...

So, you website guru's. What am I doing wrong and can you help me out?
You can find the code by clicking on the second link. Uploaded it there.

EDIT:
Nevermind the blur, managed to solve it partially with this code

```
if (blurred) {
     ctx.shadowColor = color;
     ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
     ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
     ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Stig Runar Vangen has the correct answer.

I would just add that if you don't intend the circles to "run", you could use ctx.closePath after drawing each ctx.arc.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, diameter, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.closePath();
color = color.replace('opacity', Math.random().toString());
ctx.fillStyle = color;
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see that all your circles gets the same color, might be because you join all circles into one draw operation. To separate each circle draw operation, start each circle placement with:

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

Each arc should then also be drawn with a call to either **ctx.stoke()** or **ctx.fill()** *after* the definition of each single circle.

This is purely guesswork as I haven't seen your code.

Comment: Thnx for the right direction. I tried something with `ctx.beginPath()` but it seemed not to work. But markE's solution works. Thnx guys!